# SocketIO support in playframework

Tags: playframework, socket.io

Im working on a project where i need to use socket.io at client end and play framework at server. Is there any built in support for socket.io in play frame work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in support for Socket.io in Play Framework at the moment. But it will probably come later (as I read in the Play Framework discussion group).

Comment: @AliRaza: I can't find it at the moment, only this: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/7f8c428bf148808a/834d32a1ecd31088

Comment: Maybe pusher could be an alternative. See here http://pusher.com/docs or for play integration: http://www.playframework.org/modules/pusher 
Pusher uses his own API to encapsulate the websocket calls and uses flash as a fallback. I'll give it a try.